# existence of sequence of polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a sequence of polynomials $P_n$ such that

$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(z) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{Im } z > 0\\
0, & z \text{ is real,} \\
-1, & \text{Im } z < 0
\end{cases}$

I have no clue where to start from. Please provide some hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of Runge's approximation theorem?

Comment: Ok I have read the statement now, then how can we apply this here?

Answer (score 9):

What we need of [Runge's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_theorem) is that if $K \subset\mathbb{C}$ is compact such that $\mathbb{C}\setminus K$ is connected, and $f$ holomorphic on $K$ (that means that there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $K$ and $f\colon U\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic), then there is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly **on** $K$ to $f$.

Here, a single compact $K$ is not sufficient, we need a sequence $K_n$ of compact sets exhausting the plane.

---

Letting $A_n = \left\{ z \in\mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant n \land \operatorname{Im} z \geqslant \frac{1}{n} \right\}$, $B_n = \left\{ z \in\mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant n \land \operatorname{Im} z \leqslant -\frac{1}{n} \right\}$ and $C_n = \left\{ z\in\mathbb{C} : \lvert \operatorname{Re} z\rvert \leqslant n \land \operatorname{Im} z = 0\right\}$,  we obtain an increasing sequence of compact sets $K_n = A_n\cup B_n \cup C_n$ with $\bigcup K_n = \mathbb{C}$. For all $n \geqslant 1$, the complement of $K_n$ is connected, so by Runge's theorem, there is a polynomial $P_n$ with $\lvert P_n(z)-1\rvert < \frac{1}{n}$ on $A_n$, $\lvert P_n(z)+1\rvert <\frac{1}{n}$ on $B_n$ and $\lvert P_n(z)\rvert < \frac{1}{n}$ on $C_n$.

Comment: So here we have to consider three cases: when f(z)=1, 0 and -1. For f(z)=1 we have to consider K as Im z $\geq 0$? Then its complement is connected. but at Im z =0 the function f(z) is defined 0. I am not getting the solution. Please elaborate the last line of your answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The compact sets $K_n$ should not be connected. You have three conditions, so three components would be a natural approach.

Comment: Old response here, but I have a question. Why is $C_n$ defined differently than the others? Also, why are we choosing $|z| \leq n$? Don't we just need the second conditions in each set? What's the importance of that? Also, why is the complement connected? I'm not quite seeing it.